# How to calculate the pressure and velocity of an ionised gas that is being impelled with magnetic pressure

Tags: current, electromagnetism, pressure, gas, ionization

Calculating the velocity and pressure of an ionised gas based on magnetic pressure and magnetic force.

Questions:

1. Based on magnetic pressure expressed on an ionised gas, how do I calculate the current flow in amperes?

The magnetic field is rotating and thus the ionised gas inside the conductive & magnetic material (iron) expresses its flow as an alternating current.

2. Based on the magnetic force implied within the system, how do I calculate the speed at which the ionised gas flows throughout the system?

If it matters, the magnets that are not in rotation will change the current from AC-DC as it only allows one way flow like a diode.  How would the change in current types affect the pressure of the gas?

Comment: I suggest you try physics stack exchange.